# My hot water stopped working in one bathroom, what can I try in order to fix it?

Tags: bathroom, water, water-heater

I have an electric water heater from 2004.  The hot water works in all other areas of my house (kitchen, other bathroom and washing machine).  The sinks and shower in my master bathroom are not producing hot water, only cold water.

Comment: When you turn it to hot, does it run cold, or is there no water? Was this a sudden change and has hot water come out before? Do you have separate knobs for hot/cold, or one knob to turn for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting hot everywhere else, but not in the bath, then the hot water flow has been interrupted.  Check the shutoff valves in your house - the most likely suspect is that someone's turned one off (possibly as a prank).

If all the valves are confirmed open, then the next question is, what kind of water lines do you have?  If you have galvanized pipe, it's known to corrode, so a possible culprit would be a buildup of corrosion in the line to the bathroom to the point where no or almost no water flows.

Comment: It's also a remote possibility that he has a separate water heater for that bathroom for some reason.